# VBScript Screen Resolution in RDP

Tags: vbscript

I am getting the current screen resolution with:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_VideoController",,48)

For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "Horizontal resolution: " & objItem.CurrentHorizontalResolution 
    Wscript.Echo "Vertical resolution: " & objItem.CurrentVerticalResolution
```

However it returns the resolution of the real monitor and doesn't work in an RDP session. How can I either get the RDP resolution or just get the session type to prove I am in an RDP session (and can therefore implement a work around)? This is a major issue when RDPing from a MacBook with a high resolution.

Thanks

Comment: Your RDP client should allow you to set the resolution of the RDP session to whatever you like.

Comment: I don't want to set the resolution - I want to get it using a logon script :)

Comment: I understood that. What I don't understand is the reason for it. An RDP session does not have a "physical" resolution.

Comment: I have machines with very different resolutions, but I can only set the background based on user. Instead I wrote a script to check the screen resolution and set a background suitable for its size - but it fails for RDP sessions.

Comment: Set the background to a solid color -> problem solved.

Comment: But not entirely helpful...